# Access code/password only restricts page access, no user registration..?

Tags: password, user-access

Does anyone know of a plugin that will allow for a simple access/invite code to be given out, and when entered, will allow access to a certain page?

I'm looking to only have one input field and no user registration needed to access a certain page of the site, and to just be able to give out unique codes that will grant access.

I can't find anything like this that isn't a full user membership plugin. Any help or point in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is a built-in feature of WordPress.

Create a page like you normally would.  Then look at the Publish box in the upper-right corner for where it says "**Visibility:** Public."

Click "Public" and you'll see some other options - "Private" and "Password Protected."

You want "Password Protected."  Check the appropriate box and enter the password of your choosing.  When others try to visit this page, they'll be presented with a password box - *not a user registration form.*